# Xcode Swift problem with JSON and Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm learning how to build a Xcode project with Swift then this problem comes up stopping me from building.
Many thanks if you could give me some solutions to my problem:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. The code should be included in the question as actual code not a photo.

Comment: The error says it all, there is no `@Protected` attribute. There was I think, a 
`@protected` in Objective-C. See also https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

Comment: The problem is solved magically, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Xcode is too old, it doesn't support features required by Alamofire. Alamofire requires Swift 5.3 and therefore Xcode 12+. If you can, upgrade to Xcode 13.3, the latest version, but you may be limited by the OS support of your hardware.